# Oracle datetime which does not exist in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, oracle, migration

I have a java program where some SQL statements are declared like in this method:

```
    public ObservableList<TSTTimeZoneConversion> retrieveTimeZoneConversions() throws TSTDBException
{
    String sql = "";
if (DBConnection.getDbType() == DBConnection.DB_ORACLE)
        sql = "SELECT tzc.tzc_id, tzc.tz_id, tzc.offset_to_utc, 
    to_char( tzc.start_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI' ) start_time, 
    to_char( tzc.end_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI' ) end_time, tz.tz_code 
    FROM timezone_conversion tzc, timezone tz WHERE tzc.tz_id = tz.tz_id ORDER BY tzc_id";
else
        sql = "SELECT STATEMENT FOR SQL SERVER";
    return TSTDB.retrieveDB(sql , TSTDB::TSTTimeZoneConversionMapper);
}
```

My problem is that for example this `DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI` does not exist in SQL Server and I could not figure out how to define a date with time. I tried it with `FORMAT` like suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  in the documentation but I do not know how exactly it works in this case.

My goal is to create a SQL Server query in the else part which is equivalent to the oracle query in the if part. I am using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: It might be easier to use a `LocalDateTime`, then format however needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a format mask which matches what you want, to use with SQL Server's `CONVERT` function.  But `FORMAT` seems to work fine here, assuming your version of SQL Server supports it:

```
SELECT
    tzc.tzc_id,
    tzc.tz_id,
    tzc.offset_to_utc,
    FORMAT(tzc.start_time, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm', 'en-US') start_time,
    FORMAT(tzc.end_time, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm', 'en-US') end_time,
    tz.tz_code 
FROM timezone_conversion tzc
INNER JOIN timezone tz
    ON tzc.tz_id = tz.tz_id
ORDER BY
    tzc_id;
```

Note: The uppercase `HH` represents hours on the 24 hour clock.  For hours on the 12 hour clock, use lowercase `hh`.